# pyenchant for spanish

Tags: python, pyenchant

Is there a pyenchant library for spanish.

I know this can help to check for English words

```
enchant.Dict("en_US")
```

But do you know any library i can use for spanish

I am using Python!

Comment: Which platform are you on? Have you read: [Adding Language Dictionaries](http://packages.python.org/pyenchant/tutorial.html#id9)?

Comment: @PedroRomano Your comment is almost an answer...

Comment: @JonClements: I know... But the different platforms have different dictionary installation details. Wanted to clarify that first.

Comment: I am using Python. (Had added that as a tag)

Comment: None of the links here work
http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries#Spanish_.28Spain.2C_....29

Answer (score 3):

### This answer is for OSX:

Enchant can be used as a front-end to the GNU Aspell language library.  You can install additional languages with [GNU Aspell](http://aspell.net) using [homebrew](http://brew.sh).

```
brew remove aspell
brew install aspell --with-lang-es --with-lang-en
```

Your python scripts now will have access to the `es` spanish language. Other languages are available and can be viewed by running `brew info aspell`.